# OpenSSL DigestInit_ex

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, hmac

I'm decrypting incoming packets with OpenSSL and i'm using EVP library to do the job and i first decrypt the packet and then calculate the hmac.

```
EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
EVP_DecryptInit_ex(ctx, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), NULL, key, iv);
EVP_DecryptUpdate(ctx, payload, &len, payload, data_len);
EVP_DecryptFinal_ex(ctx, payload + len, &len);
```

and with the HMAC

```
EVP_PKEY *skey = EVP_PKEY_new_mac_key(EVP_PKEY_HMAC, NULL, hmac_key, 32);
EVP_DigestInit_ex(md_ctx, EVP_sha256(), NULL);
EVP_DigestSignInit(md_ctx, NULL, md, NULL, skey);
EVP_DigestSignUpdate(md_ctx, hmac_payload, m+13);
EVP_DigestSignFinal(md_ctx, buff, &size);
```

Now, this works just fine but the problem is having to call the init functions every time before i decrypt and calculate HMAC which is not efficient because every packet has same decryption and HMAC key.

Is it possible to do the decryption and hmac calculation for each packet with same keys without calling the init functions every time ? Obviously if i remove them from my code the decryption and HMAC calculation do not work correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible with the OpenSSL implementation.

In OpenSSL terminology, a "context" like `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` or `EVP_MD_CTX` is a container for all of the state that is needed for **one** encryption/decryption operation, or **one** digest.  To reset a context for the next encryption/decryption, or digest (and thus to clear all the previous state), the calls to `EVP_DigestInit_ex()` and `EVP_DecryptInit_ex()` are necessary.

Another way to look at this is that you (the programmer) *could* be changing the cipher/digest algorithms, or other parameters, on each `EVP_DigestInit_ex()` or `EVP_DecryptInit_ex()` call; the underlying context does not know your intention.  Thus calling the initialization function, each time for re-using that context structure, prepares that structure for *these* initialization parameters (which might be different the next time).

Hope this helps!